Response Set-Cookie not working, but only on Cloudflare Pages/Workers
I am working on a simple app with Auth.js and Next.js. In specific, I am using it with WebAuthn authentication.
So, I have a pretty similar auth.ts setup:
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  basePath: "/auth",
  experimental: { enableWebAuthn: true },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  adapter: DrizzleAdapter(db, {
    usersTable: schema.users,
    sessionsTable: schema.sessions,
    verificationTokensTable: schema.verificationTokens,
    accountsTable: schema.accounts,
    authenticatorsTable: schema.authenticators,
  }),
  providers: [
    Passkey,
  ]
});

And then I have a pretty similar frontend (signin-button.tsx):
import { signIn } from "@/lib/auth";

export function SignIn() {
  return (
    <form
      action={async () => {
        "use server";
        await signIn();
      }}
    >
      <button
        type="submit"
      >
        Sign in
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}


When I run my app locally, everything works perfectly.
When I run my app on Vercel, everything works perfectly.
When I run my app on Cloudflare, I can't Sign In.

I have done some debugging, but cannot understand why still.
When the UI calls the POST /auth/callback/passkey endpoint, the following Response header is returned:
__Secure-authjs.challenge=; Max-Age=0; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax, __Secure-authjs.session-token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwia2lkIjoibFZWQkpCOFhRbUZPTFBDbElkNVZpTFdhY0JyVUl0emRVTVg1b1FEdGZkeERpVVlabXhUUjlfdzFxeE9paUlSbUFVZ01RdTU4SVZGMEZVVHplOXhvdmcifQ..3P1NvZbR8CXT-Xa7qKwCuQ.uKAx8IfKPPeAUZXc1W4sJCfWC2gAAEdZpSHvr_eV1XrlJnxUKRlsgBi67kXheLsB-cy7ljM44sccynCPtObQlvRvn5fZiqo4Chi_1UU8Em57KUA5m_vJVQ2jeN8H6dlqvfBQoq7U89qCfT11SkKtEzfQDLtlyD2dalEfUUVvB_yv4fgoVD4_NAy4lYz6MJOHNi8W71II6l7U5TsIIVAsuTjtkdntWUVyTGo4sZF8wLWp0SvFtAYH40s7fkvtLFJX.UQ8wANChM2gk-8SyAzqCANM1G3FF5YSAoNN1wK5Dk0w; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 06 Aug 2024 17:16:55 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Lax

But then, when I look at the Cookies tab for that network request, the __Secure-authjs.session-token cookie is not included in the "Response Cookies":

Compared to Vercel, where it is included for the same network request:

We can also compare the network requests themselves (first Cloudflare, then Vercel):


There are a few interesting differences:

Vercel splits up the Set-Cookie response headers into two
Vercel always sends Strict-Transport-Security as max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload

However, I cannot understand why the response cookie would work for the exact same app hosted on Vercel, but not on Cloudflare Pages/Workers.

Cloudflare seem to be in the wrong here.
According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265

Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into a single header field.

